# Highcharts variation (%) between yaxis values in tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a really simple spline chart and I'm trying to show on each tooltip the variation between the selected point and the previous point's value, measured in percentage variation. Basically **[this](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare)** is the tooltip format I want to show

I've been looking for a solution but the only thing I came up with was **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/PhW3t/55/)**.

Hope it helps.

This are my chart options:

```
GeneralChartOptions = {

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'dummycontainer',
        type: 'spline',
        zoomType: 'x',
        spacingRight: 20
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            month: '%b \'%y',
            year: '%b'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        plotLines: []
    },
    tooltip: {
        xDateFormat: '%m-%Y',
        shared: true, 
        crosshairs: true,
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    labels: {
       formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2,".",",");

       }
    },
    series: []
}
```

Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

How about look how they do and then try ?

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
    valueDecimals: 2
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        compare: 'percent'
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KHfW9/)